# MySQL: IS NULL in joined tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having some difficulty with my JOIN and IS NULL..

Basically what I want to do is find all members who are not apart of certain group category ID's that I specify.

```
SELECT m.* FROM elvanto_members AS m
    LEFT JOIN elvanto_groups AS g ON g.deleted = 0
    LEFT JOIN elvanto_groups_categories AS gc ON gc.group_id = g.id AND (gc.category_id = '1' OR gc.category_id = '2')
    WHERE gr.id IS NULL
```

Some members aren't apart of any group categories at all which is why I've made it a LEFT JOIN.

Am I making sense? Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You do not have a table named gr - What should that be an alias for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.* FROM elvanto_members AS m
WHERE 
  not exists 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM 
     elvanto_groups AS g 
      INNER JOIN elvanto_groups_categories AS gc ON 
        gc.group_id = g.id
    WHERE
     gc.category_id IN ('1','2') AND
     g.id = m.group_id AND
     g.deleted = 0
  )
```

Comment: I'm assuming there is a join between members and groups based on the an attribute of members named group_id.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   elvanto_members AS m
LEFT   JOIN elvanto_groups AS g ON g.id = m.group_id AND g.deleted = 0
LEFT   JOIN elvanto_groups_categories AS gc ON gc.group_id = g.id
                                           AND gc.category_id IN ('1','2')
WHERE  gc.group_id IS NULL
GROUP  BY m.*
```

I filled in on spec what was missing in the question.
Is `category_id` really a string type? I would expect it to be numeric. Then this expression should be:

```
 AND gc.category_id IN (1,2)
```